# Can't install Gearman on Red Hat

Tags: php, nginx, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm having problems installing Gearman from Red Hat on Amazon. I couldn't find a repo so I downloaded Gearman version .25, installed it and installed drizzle from their repo using:

```
yum install libdrizzle-devel
yum install libdrizzle
```

The command I execute is:

```
libdrizzle_CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include" libdrizzle_LIBS="-L/usr/local/lib -ldrizzle" ./configure
```

I get:

```
   * Installation prefix:       /usr/local
   * System type:               unknown-linux-gnu
   * Host CPU:                  x86_64
   * C Compiler:                gcc (GCC) 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6)
   * Assertions enabled:        yes
   * Debug enabled:             no
   * Warnings as failure:       no
   * Building with libsqlite3   no
   * Building with libdrizzle   yes
   * Building with libmemcached no
   * Building with libpq        no
   * Building with tokyocabinet no
```

Then I do:

```
make
make install
```

Followed by:

```
pecl install gearman
```

However it appears that I cannot use the drizzle library and running gearmand gives me a blank screen.

It's on an nginx server and restarting the php-fpm also gives me errors:

```
Gracefully shutting down php-fpm . done
Starting php-fpm PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/gearman.so' - libgearman.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Am I doing something wrong? Are there other ways of install Gearman?

Answer (score 0):

After installing your PHP module, you need to add the reference to `/etc/php.ini`